# "We can not play tennis today because it (rain or rains or is raining)."

Tags: sentence-construction

> We can not play tennis today because it (rain or rains or is raining).

Which tense should I use?

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/384/216106) for related info.

Answer (score 3):

*Because it rain* is ungrammatical.

*Because it rains* (like most simple presents) is used for timeless or habitual senses, not for present time.

> *Trees grow readily in that region because it rains a lot.*

> *We don't like staying there because it rains nearly every day.*

But for present time:

> *We cannot play tennis today because it is raining.*